# How to select all fields of joined entities using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables:
Limit_utilisation_history with fields:

- bigint limit_utilisation_history_id (PK)
- numeric(20,2) utilisation_amount
- bigint limit_id (FK to limit_utilisation table)

Limit_utilisation with fields:

- bigint limit_id (PK)
- varchar customer_id

So both tables are related.
I need to expose the result of the following query via rest call:

```
select limit_utilisation_history_id, utilisation_amount, limit_id, customer_id
where customer_id in (some list of values)
```

I have done it in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class LimitUtilisation{
 @Id
 private Long limitIdl
 private String customerId;
}

@Entity
@Data
@NamedQuery{
 name = "LimitUtilisationHistory.getByCustomer",
 query = "FROM LimitUtilisationHistory luh FETCH ALL PROPERTIES " +
         "INNER JOIN luh.limitId al " +
         "WHERE al.customerId in :values"
}
public class LimitUtilisationHistory{
 @Id
 private Long limitUtilisationHistoryId;
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "limit_id", referencedColumnName = "limitId")
 private LimitUtilisation limitId;
}

public interface LimitUtilisationHistoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LimitUtilisationHistory, Long> {
 @RestResource(path = "byCustomerId")
 @Query
 List<LimitUtilisationHistory> getByCustomer (@Param("values") List<String> customer);
}
```

It works fine, however when I call my rest endpoint I have only utilisation_amount value, others (mainly PK, FK, customer id are missing).
Does anyone have an idea how to do it correctly?

```
select limit_utilisation_history_id, utilisation_amount, limit_id, customer_id
where customer_id in (some list of values)
```

Remark: I cannot update DB structure. My intention is to only read from existing DB structure

Answer (score 1):

As you you using FetchType.EAGER I don't see any reason of using FETCH ALL in the query, Could you please try with the below query :

```
select luh.limit_utilisation_history_id, luh.utilisation_amount, luh.limit_id, lu.customer_id 
from LimitUtilisationHistory luh , LimitUtilisation lu
where luh.limit_id = lu.limit_id 
and lu.customerId in :values
```

Comment: failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type LimitUtilisationHistory for value java.lang.Object